# Notepad++ Column lenght of a text

Tags: notepad++

i forget the regex for this but i have list with text like this one:

> muro33:s574474 < 7 char
>
> iklexi:b51111  < 6 char
>
> don523:uez3w4 < 6 char
>
> sonic353:**l5431** **< 5 char**

how to delte multilines with 5 char after delim

Answer (score 0):

`(.+?):.{5}$` - this regex might be helpful

```
(.+?)   # lazy capturing of all characters before colon
:       # matches colon
.{5}    # matches any 5 characters
$       # matches the end of the string
```